# Send parameter to PHP Unit on the command line

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to send a parameter to PHP Unit using the command line.

e.g.

```
./phpunit --foo='bar' AllTests
```

How can I do this?

The closest I was able to achieve my objective is using the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <env name="foo" value="bar"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I can then access the variable using `$_ENV['foo']`.

However, I want to send this variable using the command line.

Answer (score 17):

Using `phpunit.xml` is obviously for constant environmental variables and using it for passing changing parameters to tests is a bit of an overhead.

What you can do is one of the following (see [Passing parameters to PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094970/passing-parameters-to-phpunit) for the discussion):

### Use setting environmental variables for the command

*Example:* `FOO=bar ./phpunit AllTests`

**Pros:** Trivial.

**Cons:** Depends on environment; requires remembering names of the variables (which is not that simple if there are many); no obvious documentation on supported/necessary parameters available.

### Use **$argv** for passing parameters and using them inside your test.

*Example:* `./phpunit AllTests bar`

**Pros**: Trivial; independent from environment; no limitations to PHPUnit parameters.

**Cons:** Will be a pain if there are more than several arguments, especially if most of them are optional; no obvious documentation for expected arguments.

### Use setting **environmental variables** (and then running tests) with your own runner script/function

*Example:* `. run.sh AllTests bar` where `run.sh` looks at the provided arguments and exports them into the environment.

**Pros:** Still more or less trivial to implement; adds documentation of the expected argument list; adds error handling (e.g. in case `bar` is a required parameter, but is not provided).

**Cons:** PHPUnit parameters inside runner are hardcoded; dependent on the environment.

### Fork PHPUnit and implement your own supported parameters in the extended command parser

*Example:* `./phpunit --foo='bar' AllTests`

**Pros:** Does exactly what you want.

**Cons:** Not so trivial to implement; requires forking which makes it strongly dependent on CLI of the current PHPUnit version.

### Write your own runner with your own command parser

*Example:* `run.sh --foo=bar --coverage-html=baz` where `run.sh` calls some `run.php` which in its turn runs command arguments through parser, builds the command for running tests and does that.

**Pros:** Now you can do whatever you like and add any parameters you need. You can implement your own logger, you can run tests in multithread etc.

**Cons:** Hard to implement; sometimes needs maintenance; is strongly dependent on PHPUnit CLI.

Comment: The option of simply passing parameters on the command-line seem to have been removed at some point - running `./phpunit AllTests bar` with recent phpunit versions will result in an error message 'file bar not found'...

Answer (score 5):

You can run any command with environment variable set:

`foo=bar ./phpunit AllTests`