# Laravel/Phpunit: is it possible to force DB connection via terminal?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have a Laravel project.

I want test it on my develop machine + Travis/Scrutinizer with SQLite, plus I want test on another machine with MySQL.

This is my PHPUnit file that works like a charme

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <!-- and this is where your report will be written -->
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="./logs/clover.xml"/>
    </logging>
    <php>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I'm asking: is there a possibility to launch on a linux shell command a similar command (pseudocode, of course):

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --db_connection=mysql
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to edit the `phpunit.xml` file dynamically from the command line by default, but you can set the `DB_CONNECTION` environment variable (and other variables) like this:

`DB_CONNECTION=mysql ./vendor/bin/phpunit`

You can view more options for setting environment variables in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662597/4593376) answer.