# How to unit test 3rd party API endpoints that need access_token?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a backend API that consumes **Github's API** to retrieve some repos and do some stuff with it. Also I'm using **Codeship CI**, so all my data need to be in the code in order to be properly built.

There's a route in my backend `/api/github/repos` that takes an Github `access_token` as parameter and consumes `https://api.github.com/user/repos` endpoint which lists all logged user repositories.

My doubt is: **how do I unit test this route?** I cannot write my `access_token` in the unit test since it's sensitive data and I'm storing it in Github public repository nor I can seed that data to a database because the `access_token` will still be written in the code. Where should I keep my `access_token`? Is there another approach?

I'm developing in PHP using Laravel framework but as you can see this problem is language independent.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this:

1. Use a test table / file (or .env) / cache key value pair, store the api key in the test table / file / cache and then retrieve the key in the unit test, which passes the params to the request for testing
2. Pass [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094970/passing-parameters-to-phpunit) arguments to phpunit
3. Use a repository interface to fetch the api key in your controller class. You can have 2 repository class implementations of this interface - the first fetching the key from the request param and the second fetching the key from say a test table / file / cache as in point #1

There may be other ways as well. Which one you choose would depend on your app. If the api key is relevant for most unit tests, you may go for #2, else #1. #3 would be ideal for large apps - more layers of abstraction and cleaner code but over-engineering for small/mid apps